# (VW CC 2010 2.0L Sport) How do you diagnose a parasitic battery drain from a fuse that controls rear window raisers and central locking system?

Tags: electrical, vw, battery-drain, power-windows, central-locking

My 2010 VW CC is having a parasitic drain issue and I've isolated the problem to one of the fuses which is for the rear window raisers and for the central locking system. If I keep this fuse out overnight, I can start my car but if I leave it in and lock my car, it drains within a couple of hours and I have to jump my car. The problem with leaving this fuse out and calling it a day is that you're unable to lock the car.
How do I begin to troubleshoot this issue?
Where exactly is the "central locking system"?

Answer (score 1):

You start by isolating each component connected to that fuse / circuit and finding out which one is causing the drain.

A process of elimination and it helps if you approach this logically ie disconnect all and reconnect one component at a time.